# PHP preg_match return false

Tags: php, regex

I tried this regex syntax in http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ and seem working well.

```
^[a-z0-9-]+.([a-z]{2,4})$
```

the purpose is to match domain name(not containing http or https)

so i use `preg_match( '/^[a-z0-9-]+.([a-z]{2,4})$/g', 'fathi-hadi.net' )`
but always return false

i don't know why

Comment: you may want to escape the `.` =>  `\.`, the dot matches any character.

Comment: yes, you are right, thanks to mention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you turn on error reporting, you would've noticed `preg_match` doesn't support the `g` modifier:

> Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier 'g'

So drop that and use:

```
preg_match('/^[a-z0-9-]+\.([a-z]{2,4})$/', 'fathi-hadi.net');
```

That will match. I also incorporated Gerald Schneider's comment about escaping the dot, which is a good point.

Comment: Yes, it match now, Thanks Oldskool

Comment: There is still a bug with the dot -- as it is now, it will match any character, which isn't the intended result.

Comment: @SDC : yes, in the first comment, Gerald Schneider already mention about that. Thanks you